# CTE to traverse back up a hierarchy?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, hierarchy, common-table-expression

I can find all the children of a given record in a hierarchical data model (see code below) but I'm not sure how to traverse back up the Parent/Child chain with a given Child ID.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to figure out how to do this?  Is this possible in Linq to SQL as well?

```
WITH TaskHierarchy (TaskID, [Subject], ParentID, HierarchyLevel, HierarchyPath) AS
(
   -- Base case
   SELECT
      TaskID,
      [Subject],
      ParentID,
      1 as HierarchyLevel,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),'/') AS HierarchyPath
   FROM Task
   WHERE TaskID = 2

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive step
   SELECT
      t.TaskID,
      t.Subject,
      t.ParentID,
      th.HierarchyLevel + 1 AS HierarchyLevel,
      CONVERT(varchar(MAX),th.HierarchyPath + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),t.ParentID) + '/') AS HierarchyPath
   FROM Task t
      INNER JOIN TaskHierarchy th ON
         t.ParentID = th.TaskID
)

SELECT *
FROM TaskHierarchy
ORDER BY HierarchyLevel, [Subject]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out:

```
WITH Hierarchy(TaskID, [Subject], ParentID, IsProject, HLevel)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        TaskID, 
        [Subject], 
        ParentID ,
        IsProject,
        0 as HLevel
    FROM 
        Task 
    WHERE 
        TaskID = 59

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        SubDepartment.TaskID, 
        SubDepartment.[Subject], 
        SubDepartment.ParentID ,
        SubDepartment.IsProject,
        HLevel + 1
    FROM 
        Task SubDepartment
    INNER JOIN 
        Hierarchy ParentDepartment
    ON 
        SubDepartment.TaskID = ParentDepartment.ParentID 
)

SELECT 
    TaskID, 
    [Subject], 
    ParentID,
    IsProject,
    HLevel
FROM  
    Hierarchy
ORDER BY
    HLevel DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution! It has saved me hours!